# Swift: How to pass in a closure as a function argument

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to figure out the syntax for passing in a closure (completion handler) as an argument to another function.

My two functions are:

#### Response Handler:

```
func responseHandler(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void {
    var err: NSError


    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
    println("AsSynchronous\(jsonResult)")

}
```

#### Query Function

```
public func queryAllFlightsWithClosure( ) {

    queryType = .AllFlightsQuery
    let urlPath = "/api/v1/flightplan/"
    let urlString : String = "http://\(self.host):\(self.port)\(urlPath)"
    var url : NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    var request : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:responseHandler)

}
```

I'd like to modify the Query to something like:

```
public fund queryAllFlightsWithClosure( <CLOSURE>) {
```

so that I can externally pass the closure into the function.  I know there is some support for training closures but I"m not sure if thats the way to go either.  I can't seem to get the syntax correct...

I've tried:

```
public func queryAllFlightsWithClosure(completionHandler : {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void} ) {
```

but it keeps giving me an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OOPS nevermind...

```
public func queryAllFlightsWithClosure(completionHandler : (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void ) {
```

took out the {} and it seems to work?

Comment: Yes that's correct - brackets to be used when you implement the closure body

Answer (score 12):

It might help defining a type alias for the closure:

```
public typealias MyClosure = (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void
```

that makes the function signature "lighter" and more readable:

```
public func queryAllFlightsWithClosure(completionHandler : MyClosure ) {        
}
```

However, just replace `MyClosure` with what it is aliasing, and you have the right syntax:

```
public func queryAllFlightsWithClosure(completionHandler : (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void ) {
}
```

Comment: but how to pass return values in Closure