# Swift is giving non-void return error even though it is set to Double?

Tags: swift, function, swift3, return, double

I am getting this error:

```
/Users/xxxx/Desktop/xxx/xxx/ViewController.swift:43:38: Unexpected non-void return value in void function
```

And others like this even though my functions are set to return Double.

This is one of the functions of which this error is appearing in every return.

```
func readWeight() -> Double {
    let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass)

    let weightQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: quantityType!, predicate: nil, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: nil) {

        query, results, error in

        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!)
            return 0.0
        }

        guard let results = results else {
            print("No results of query")
            return 0.0
        }

        if (results.count == 0) {
            print("Zero samples")
            return 0.0
        }

        guard let bodymass = results[0] as? HKQuantitySample else {
            print("Type problem with weight")
            return 0.0
        }
        return bodymass.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.pound())
    }

    healthKitStore.execute(weightQuery)
}
```

An example of how this is used:

```
print(readWeight())
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to return something in the block you are passing to `HKSampleQuery`, that is not going to work, the block does not have a return type. You have to use completion blocks for your method `readWeight` as well or wait in some fashion for the completion of the `HKSampleQuery`.

Comment: is that `HKSampleQuery` function an synchronized one? If so, you need to use block and completion handler

Comment: @FangmingNing Just learned it is async so I have to wait for the value... this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44701636/4285493 seems to be working but comparing it does not seem to work

Comment: Posted my answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to use block. So the function itself will return void. When the `HKSampleQuery` starts, it get executed and waiting for result while your `readWeight` function keep executing and then end returning void. By this time, your `HKSampleQuery` is still executing. When it is done, it posts result by the completion handler. So if you want to do anything with the result `Double`, you need to do it in the completion handler. So your function will be

```
func readWeight(completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
   let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass)

   let weightQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: quantityType!, predicate: nil, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: nil) {

    query, results, error in

    if (error != nil) {
        print(error!)
        completion(0.0)
    }

    guard let results = results else {
        print("No results of query")
        completion(0.0)
    }

    if (results.count == 0) {
        print("Zero samples")
        completion(0.0)
    }

    guard let bodymass = results[0] as? HKQuantitySample else {
        print("Type problem with weight")
        completion(0.0)
    }
    completion(bodymass.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.pound()))
}

   healthKitStore.execute(weightQuery)
}
```

To use the result:

```
self.readWeight(){ (result) in
    //This result is a double value that is returned from HKSampleQuery
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to return Double value at the end of function.

```
 func readWeight() -> Double {
 let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass)

let weightQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: quantityType!, predicate: nil, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: nil) {

    query, results, error in

    if (error != nil) {
        print(error!)
        return 0.0
    }

    guard let results = results else {
        print("No results of query")
        return 0.0
    }

    if (results.count == 0) {
        print("Zero samples")
        return 0.0
    }

    guard let bodymass = results[0] as? HKQuantitySample else {
        print("Type problem with weight")
        return 0.0
    }
    return bodymass.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.pound())
}

healthKitStore.execute(weightQuery)
return some double value here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that what you want to achieve is something like that:

```
func readWeight(result: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
   let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass)

   let weightQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: quantityType!, predicate: nil, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: nil) {

    query, results, error in

    if (error != nil) {
        print(error!)
        result(0.0)
    }

    guard let results = results else {
        print("No results of query")
        result(0.0)
    }

    if (results.count == 0) {
        print("Zero samples")
        result(0.0)
    }

    guard let bodymass = results[0] as? HKQuantitySample else {
        print("Type problem with weight")
        result(0.0)
    }
    result(bodymass.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.pound()))
}

   healthKitStore.execute(weightQuery)
}
```

Then you can use `readWeight` method like that:

```
readWeight(result: { myResult in
    let comparisonResult = myResult == 0.0
})
```

So that `myResult` here is the value you are looking for.

This is all caused by the fact that `HKSampleQuery` executes asynchronously, so you have no way of immediately knowing the return value. You have to wait for its result, and then process the result in a closure that was given as your method's argument.

Probably you should read more about closures:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

[Swift: How to pass in a closure as a function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632129/swift-how-to-pass-in-a-closure-as-a-function-argument)

Comment: This kind of works but I am getting this error when comparing it `/Users/xxx/Desktop/xx/xx/ViewController.swift:161:27: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '(@escaping (Double) -> Void) -> ()' and 'Double'` when doing something like `if (self.readWeight == 0.0)`

Answer (score 0):

The lines inside the braces at the end of:

```
let weightQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: quantityType!, predicate: nil, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: nil) { ... }
```

are actually part of another closure sent as an argument to `HKSampleQuery`'s initializer. Think of them as a separate function which will be executed when you call `healthKitStore.execute(weightQuery)`. As noted in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hksamplequery/1615055-init) the signature of that closure is: `(HKSampleQuery, [HKSample]?, Error?) -> Void`. This means that you can't return anything from the statements inside that closure.

Keeping that in mind, you can modify your method as follows:

```
func printWeight() {
    let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass)

    let weightQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: quantityType!, predicate: nil, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: nil) {

        query, results, error in

        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!)
        }

        guard let results = results else {
            print("No results of query")
        }

        if (results.count == 0) {
            print("Zero samples")
        }

        guard let bodymass = results[0] as? HKQuantitySample else {
            print("Type problem with weight")
        }

        print("Bodymass:",  bodymass.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.pound()))
    }

    healthKitStore.execute(weightQuery)
}
```

and then just call `printWeight()` to get the results.