# Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type '(@escaping (Double) -> Void) -> ()' and 'Double'?

Tags: swift, swift3

I asked a swift question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44701271/swift-is-giving-non-void-return-error-even-though-it-is-set-to-double) and received this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44701636/5615509) of which got rid of the error but now I am receiving a new one.

```
Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type '(@escaping (Double) -> Void) -> ()' and 'Double'
```

The code now looks like:

```
func readWeight(result: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMass)

    let weightQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: quantityType!, predicate: nil, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: nil) {

        query, results, error in

        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!)
            result(0.0)
        }

        guard let results = results else {
            print("No results of query")
            result(0.0)
        }

        if (results.count == 0) {
            print("Zero samples")
            result(0.0)
        }

        guard let bodymass = results[0] as? HKQuantitySample else {
            print("Type problem with weight")
            result(0.0)
        }
        result(bodymass.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.pound()))
    }

    healthKitStore.execute(weightQuery)
}
```

and I am getting this error whenever I try to multiply it like:

```
self.readWeight * 0.67
```

Thanks!

Comment: Self.readWeight is a function that doesn't return anything. What do you expect this to do?

Comment: It seems to be returning values but I will try a print statement to set it @Fogmeister

Comment: @Fogmeister Yep it does not seem to be returning anything just getting another error `/Users/andrewrodebaugh/Desktop/Aqua/Aqua/ViewController.swift:67:13: 'guard' body may not fall through, consider using a 'return' or 'throw' to exit the scope`

Comment: @brimstone Tells me to remove parenthesis

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44702859/5615509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `readWeight` does not return anything, it uses a closure as an asynchronous callback.

The appropriate syntax is

```
readWeight() { weight in
    let result = weight * 0.67
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Seems to work minus the fact I am now getting `/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/xxx/ViewController.swift:77:13: 'guard' body may not fall through, consider using a 'return' or 'throw' to exit the scope` in all the result() in the function. Sorry I am really new to swift and really good at breaking things.

Comment: The solution depends on the context the method is called in.

Comment: A `guard` expression must have an exit statement in its body.

Comment: @arodebaugh If a guard clause like `guard let x = ... else { ... }` was allowed to fallthrough, you would find yourself in a spot after the guard clause, but without `x` being set to anything. It wouldn't make any sense